# need help changing single character in char*

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm getting back into c++ and have the hang of pointers and whatnot, however, I was hoping I could get some help understanding why this code segment gives a bus error.

```
char * str1 = "Hello World";
*str1 = '5';
```

ERROR: Bus error :(

And more generally, I am wondering how to change the value of a single character in a cstring. Because my understanding is that *str = '5' should change the value that str points to from 'H' to '5'. So if I were to print out str it would read: "5ello World".

In an attempt to understand I wrote this code snippet too, which works as expected;

```
char test2[] = "Hello World";
char *testpa2 = &test2[0];
*testpa2 = '5';
```

This gives the desired output. So then what is the difference between testpa2 and str1? Don't they both point to the start of a series of null-terminated characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say `char *str = "Hello World";` you are making a pointer to a literal string which is not changeable.  It should be required to assign the literal to a `const char*` instead, but for historical reasons this is not the case (oops).

When you say `char str[] = "Hello World;"` you are making an array which is initialized to (and sized by) a string known at compile time.  This is OK to modify.

Answer (score 5):

Not so simple. :-)

The first one creates a *pointer* to the given string literal, which is allowed to be placed in read-only memory.

The second one creates an *array* (on the stack, usually, and thus read-write) that is initialised to the contents of the given string literal.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example you try to modify a string literal, this results in undefined behavior.

As per the language standard in **2.13.4.2**

> Whether  all  string  literals  are 
>   distinct  (that  is,  are  stored  in 
>   nonoverlapping objects) is 
>   implementation-defined.  *The effect of
>   attempting to modify a string literal
>   is undefined*.

In your second example you used string-literal initialization, defined in **8.5.2.1**

> A char array (whether plain char,
>   signed char, or unsigned char) can be
>   initialized by a string- literal
>   (optionally enclosed in braces); a
>   wchar_t array can be initialized by a
>   wide string-literal (option- ally 
>   enclosed  in  braces);  successive 
>   characters  of  the  string-literal 
>   initialize  the  members  of  the 
>   array.